# $n!$ computation in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model

Tags: computational-complexity

It is well known that if $n!$ cannot be computed in $\mathsf{polylog}(n)$ ring ($\Bbb Z$) operations, then $\mathsf P\neq\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model.

Suppose if we assume $\mathsf P=\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model (and hence in Turing model), is there an hypothetical procedure that can be explictly written out that would compute $n!$ in $\mathsf{polylog}(n)$ ring ($\Bbb Z$) operations?

Comment: Does it matter that $n!$ can be computed in subexponential time? For SAT this would mean collapse AFAICT.

Comment: Why would $n!$ in subexp time collapse $\mathsf{SAT}$? Is there a direct connection between $n!$ and $\mathsf{SAT}$?

Comment: I know that $\mathsf{permanent}$ is easy implies $n!$ is easy. I do not know of connection to $\mathsf{SAT}$.

Comment: No, I don't claim subexp n! implies SAT collapse. Just asking if it implies something else, since subexp results are not trivial. I meant subexp SAT would imply SAT collapse.

Comment: What does phrase 'subexp SAT would imply SAT collapse' imply?

Comment: If I remember correctly (will try to find reference), subexp SAT implies P=NP.

Comment: @joro That would be interesting. I do not know of such result. So what does n! have to do with SAT (you mentioned on n! in subexp 'For SAT this would mean collapse AFAICT')?

Comment: This was just an analogy with SAT and NP_C vs NP. I was asking, didn't claim anything.

Comment: Turbo, check [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/are-there-subexponential-time-algorithms-for-np-complete-problems). It depends how subexp is exactly defined. From there: "If by subexpoential you mean $2^{n^{o(1)}}$, then a conjecture in complexity theory called ETH (Exponential Time Hypothesis) implies that no $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problem can have an algorithm with running-time $2^{n^{o(1)}}$."

Comment: This does not imply $\mathsf{SAT}$ collapses (if collapses mean poly time).

Comment: OK, maybe this will collapse just ETH. btw, this is somewhat related to intermediate problems.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis Some sources define the exponential time hypothesis to be the slightly weaker statement that 3-SAT cannot be solved in time $2^{o(n)}$.